# deploy qt application on mac

Tags: macos, qt, deployment

I tried to use `macdeployqt` to deploy my project.

When I run `macdeployqt` project name.app, I got following error messages:

> ERROR: Unexpected prefix "@loader_path"

My Qt version: 5.12.0

Does anyone know what happens?

Comment: From where are you deploying libraries to the app?  Have you run `otool -L` on your executable binary, amd resolved dependencies with `install_name_tool`?  Have you checked for the correct rpath(s) with `otool -l`.  Did you link every dependency at the end of compilation?  Can you post the full error?